# Status 403 Invalid CSRF token in Post request from Postman

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to hit an endpoint from Postman, but I am getting

```
 {
    "status":403,"message":"Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.",
    "errorCode":2,"timestamp":1577971981970
  }
```

There is a class which extends 
`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` where I tried to configure and allow this endpoint

```
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("api/reset-password/**")
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

I still get the same result. I even tried to completely disable the CSRF in the application.properties with `security.enable-csrf=false` but the result is the same
I also tried to hit other endpoints which were configured before I add my new endpoint and it behaves the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Spring.io
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html

> When should you use CSRF protection? Our recommendation is to use CSRF
>   protection for any request that could be processed by a browser by
>   normal users. If you are only creating a service that is used by
>   non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection.

to disable it

```
@Configuration
public class RestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

if you want to add it to a form action do this

```
<form action="./upload?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```